# Entity framework strange mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following C# class:

```
public class SomeClass{
   public string Name;
   public List<SomeClass> List1;
   public List<SomeClass> List2;
}
```

When I have 2 instances of SomeClass (SomeClass1 and SomeClass2) and do something like:

```
SomeClass1.List1.Add(SomeClass2);
```

It also adds SomeClass1 to SomeClass2.List2 for some reason when context.SaveChanges() is called. How can I prevent this?

Edit: I am using code first.
Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to tell without seeing the mapping you created. Please provide it.

Comment: It is code first. I forgot to add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any mapping with Fluent API EF will create a mapping based on conventions. The convention in this case is that `List1` and `List2` are the *inverse* navigation properties of the same relationship - in this case a "self-referencing" many-to-many relationship.

The effect you experience is an automatic *relationship fixup* which is executed when `DetectChanges()` is called (or `SaveChanges()` which calls `DetectChanges()` internally). This fixup updates inverse navigation properties of attached entities automatically so that they are consistent with each other. You cannot prevent this and it shouldn't actually be a problem.

**Edit**

If you don't want a mapping between the two lists you must specify an explicit mapping with Fluent API. For example: If both lists belong to separate one-to-many relationships you must specify:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>()
    .HasMany(s => s.List1)
    .WithRequired()              // or WithOptional()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>()
    .HasMany(s => s.List2)
    .WithRequired()              // or WithOptional()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This mapping says that the second end of each relationship is not exposed in the model (hence `WithRequired()`/`WithOptional()` without parameter).

Similar you can specify two many-to-many relationships with `HasMany(s => s.List1/2).WithMany().Map(...)`.

Comment: Is there any way to undo this relation? It is not my intention that the lists are each others inverse.